# Wpf Treeview grouping

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have a TreeView bound to a `List<MyCustomType>`. I need to display the list grouped by `MyType.MyGroupingProperty` and show the list items themselves as leaves. How can i do that?

**What i tried**

Since I need to display the list grouped by `MyType.MyGroupingProperty`, I create a CollectionViewSource, bind it to TreeView and create HierarchicalDataTemplate:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" Source="{Binding}">
    <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="MyGroupingProperty"/>
    </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

 <HierarchicalDataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type vm:DeviceViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" >
     <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyGroupingProperty}" />
 </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

So far, so good. But now i can't display items cause DataTemplate need a type i already used and i get an exception 'key already added to dictionary'; if i use a x:key it does not work either.

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:DeviceViewModel} >
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding AnotherProperty}" />
 </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you're binding your TreeView to groups, HierarchicalDataTemplate  will deal with them and not with DeviceViewModel, so the template should be something like

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}"  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dataTemplate}">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The complete solution will look like this:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource yourCollection}, Path=Groups}" >
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <!--GroupItem.Name-->
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                         <!--your item's property-->
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Property}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Hope it helps.

P.S. I didn't know you needed the templates to be in resources, but it's possible of couse. As I haven't seen your code I can only guess what's wrong, but I suspect you specify the wrong target type, try this:

```
 <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DataType="{x:Type CollectionViewGroup}">
```

The rest is the same. If the template's type is different from the real one it will use the default way of presenting data (text blocks + `ToString()`).

Comment: Exactly, but it does not work either. Could you please provide a complete working example for me?

Comment: Great this works!  I don't get why it does not work if I place HierarchicalDataTemplate in TreeView.Resources. I'd like to know the difference but this comment section seems to be too tiny

Comment: Great! i'm wondering how did you find out.. on msdn seems like Groups and Items are ReadOnlyObservableCollection<Object> .. This seems the main reason why i use and remember wpf stuff but i don't really learn it..

Comment: FindResource() -> GetType()

Comment: I know i'm starting to annoy you since the question is solved... but i can't GetType() everytime i need to bind something to view.. that should be documentation isnt it?